# How to delete all .exe files from all subfolders of the current folder?

Tags: python

I have many .exe file stored in various subfolders of a particular folder. I want to remove all of them. Is there a python code for it?

Comment: You can use `os.walk()` to find all files underneath the current directory, and `os.remove()` to remove any file you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the subprocess library in python. You then run the command del to delete the file. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This script should work.

```py
import os

dir_path = r'PATH/TO/YOUR/DIR'
file_extenstion = '.exe' # You can change it based on your need. 

for root, _, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files: 
        if file.endswith(file_extenstion): # for each file in the dir and the sub directories, if the file name ends with the '.exe'
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, file)) # Just delete it
```